# “dagger-android” library, how to inject a property of a Dialog class?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I followed the example which claims that is the better "new way". (https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-the-new-dagger-android-module-9eb6075f1a46) The full sample source code is here (https://github.com/jshvarts/DaggerAndroidKotlinSampleApp). It uses this to inject properties to an Activity like this,

```
class MainActivity:AppCompatActivity()
{
    @Inject
    lateinit var something:Something

    override fun onCreate(..)
    {
      AndroidInjection.inject(this)
      ...
```

And a module

```
@Module
abstract class ActivitiesModule
{
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindMainActivity():MainActivity
```

It works well, but what about a custom `Dialog` class?  I create the Dialog with some custom arguments (which are only known at run-time with user's inputs) like the following. I may modify the constructor of MyDialog to take `something`, and let the activity eventually pass `something` to the MyDialog's constructor.

But it would be ugly, because the activity does not directly create MyDialog. MainActivity has a custom control, and that custom control shows MyDialog when a button is clicked on it. So, to use the constructor method, I must pass `something` from MainActivity to the custom control, and then let the custom control create MyDialog with `something`.

```
class MyDialog:Dialog
{
      @Inject
      lateinit var something:Something

      constructor(context:Context?, arg1, args2, args3):super(context)
      {
          //Cannot call AndroidInjection.inject, because
          //it does not take a Dialog.
          AndroidInjection.inject(this); //<--Does NOT work.
```

If only I could tell Dagger to inject the fields of MyDialog at its constructor... What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AndroidInjection only works on the classes like activities and fragments, not dialogs. If you want to inject your dialog, use a dialog fragment instead. Or, since you can actually just call the constructor, use constructor injection and not Dagger.

Comment: If you declare your custom Fragment's constructor, then Android won't be able to use it when configuration change occurs.